# how to get a bool from a variable of a different type in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to return true into a `const` if another `const` is inequal to null.
Everything that I have tried on crashing react.

Most Promising:

```
const isActive = plugVal !== null
```

this keeps returning true even when `plugVal` is null.

With useState hook I tried:

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

if(plugVal){
    setIsActive(true)
}
else{
    setIsActive(false)
}
```

this triggers to many re-renders

Comment: Did you try logging the value of `plugVal`??

Comment: Try to use this
!!plugVal

Ideally plugVal !== null return false if plugVal is null
Can you print the value of plugVal and Provide the image?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQn0l.png

Comment: I would recommend `const value = plugVal ? "if true equals this" : "else equals this";`

Comment: No not possible. `plugVal !== null` this will always return true if `plugVal` has any value other than `null`, you might be making some other mistake.

Comment: I used ```const isActive = plugVal ? true : false``` , and it logged out properly, but the code still didn't work. I went back and logged out ```isActive``` using the first method and it returned true, so the problem must be somewhere else in the code. Time for debug hell. yay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code of @Invizi using ternary operator. This other 2 cases also works fine.

```js
const isActive = plugVal ? true : false

const isActive = Boolean(plugVal)

const isActive = !!plugVal
```

Answer (score 0):

The !! pattern using the ! operator is specifically just for this..

[This topic covers it more in-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: !! is not an operator

Comment: True, not sure.. what I should call it? ! double-operator (!!) seems like a handful =)

Comment: It's just two logical NOT operators

Comment: Is the edit more accurate? @RobertoZvjerković